# Dixon & Price function in Python - summing elements of a list together with index number

Tags: python, list, function, sum

Consider the Dixon & Price function [here](http://al-roomi.org/benchmarks/unconstrained/n-dimensions/236-dixon-price-s-function).

How can I write this function in Python?

I tried

`def dixonprice(v):    # v is a input vector
    v2 = v.pop(0)     # since we need the sum from the second element onwards
    return (v[0]-1)**2 + sum(*(2*(x**2)-) for x in v2)`

However I cannot complete it because I don't know how to write i (i.e. the index) inside the sum. Also, I would need the element before the actual one (x _{i-1}). Normally we use `sum()` to sum over all elements, but here I got stuck.

**Edit**

I don't know how to use Mathjax here, however the expression that I am missing should be something like `sum_from_i=2_to_n = i*(2*(x_i)**2-x_(i-1))**2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I might do it. Notice the `i+1` and `range(1,...)` in the summation, since Python series are zero-indexed.

```
#UNTESTED
def dixonprice(x):
    return (x[0]-1)**2 + sum((i+1)*(2*x[i]**2-x[i-1])**2 for i in range(1, len(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you, looks great! I will test it and see if it works, but looks like it!

Comment: This function seems to have a pathological local minimum at (0.3333, 0, 0, ...) for higher dimensions, starting infrequently at about n = 4, but really persistent by n = 8.  Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
def dix(v):
    first = (v[0]-1)**2
    summ = 0
    for i in range(2,len(v)):
        partial = i*(2*v[i-1]**2 - v[i-2])**2
        summ += partial
    return first + summ
```

Some modifications are necessary since Python is 0-indexed.